# Displaying an image using a package

Tags: java, image-processing

I'm having a few problems using a package to display an image, it works perfectly well for some images but not others.  I've tried changing the image format but this doesn't make any difference, the output looks like this; http://tinypic.com/r/289bn92/5.  Is this a problem with the code? or the formatting of the image?

Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import iptoolkit.*;

public class FindArea {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    int area = 0;

    String imageDir = "C:/Users/John/Dropbox/finalYear/Project/Leaves/";
    MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();

    IntImage src = new IntImage(imageDir + "ashLeafBW.jpg", 256, 256);

    src.displayImage(); //displays the image in a window

    for (int row = 0; row < src.getRows(); row++)
    {
        for (int col=0; col < src.getCols(); col++)
        {
            int pixel = src.pixels[row][col];
            int  red = (pixel & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
            int  green = (pixel & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
            int  blue = pixel & 0x000000ff;
            // and the Java Color is ...
            Color color = new Color(red,green,blue);

            if((color.getRed() == 0) & (color.getBlue() == 0) & (color.getGreen() == 0))
                area++;
        }
    }
    System.out.print("The area of the leaf is: " +area);
  }
}
```

The program is supposed to display an image of a leaf and calculate the area of that leaf. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: *the output looks like static on a television*: what is that supposed to mean? Aren't all images static, by definition? What is this code supposed to do? Why don't you at least post the image you want, and the image you get, on some external site, and link them from here?

Comment: Without any information about what this `IntImage` and `iptoolkit` is I think it is impossible to give any meaningful answers.

Comment: OK i've made a couple of edits that I hope will help